# Why can web sites read the full path of a drag&drop dropped file?

Tags: html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

There are two options for uploading files. You can use the `input type="file"` or you can use drag and drop.

Recently I stumbled upon the fact that with drag & drop, the entire path is being transmitted to the server.

Example:

[image: Example]

(Google Chrome 32)

If this was possible with the input element, it would be an exploit. Why is it none when we use drag & drop?

Answer (score 1):

Your browser, or perhaps the flash or Java plugin used by Facebook, is transmitting the full path. It's not an "exploit" in any sense but it does seem to be an information leak.

Comment: Afaik, it's not using java or flash, but HTML 5's drag&drop ability.